# Button on the dialog box was unable to click or choose in Protractor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, protractor, material-design

[dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NlyN.jpg)Unable to get the "Start New Application" button in Protractor. The script was not retrieving the id for the start new application button

```
it("test the modal dialog button", function() {[code for the dialog box][2]

browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
browser.get("URL given");


expect(element(by.cssContainingText('.ng-star-inserted','2')).isPresent()).toBeFalsy();
expect(element(by.cssContainingText('#button-primary','Back to home')).isPresent()).toBeTruthy();


element(by.buttonText('resend')).click; 
browser.wait(3000);
element(by.cssContainingText('button-primary','Back to home')).click();
```

Once the Start new application is chosen or click. New page or URL will need to load

Comment: Please provide the html of the button you can't click

Answer (score 0):

You forgot parenthesis in this line

`element(by.buttonText('resend')).click;`

so it should have been

`element(by.buttonText('resend')).click();`